# How do I subtract one character from another in Rust?

Tags: rust, char

In Java, I could do this.

```java
int diff = 'Z' - 'A'; // 25
```

I have tried the same in Rust:

```
fn main() {
    'Z' - 'A';
}
```

but the compiler complains:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `-` cannot be applied to type `char`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     'Z' - 'A';
  |     ^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: an implementation of `std::ops::Sub` might be missing for `char`
```

How can I do the equivalent operation in Rust?

Comment: This really needs an answer, UTF-8 was deisned to be compatible with ASCII in many cases and ASCII was designed that manth makes sense, e.g for capitalization of the a-z range which is handy, even in utf.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The operation is meaningless in a Unicode world, and barely ever meaningful in an ASCII world, this is why Rust doesn't provide it directly, but there are two ways to do this depending on your use case:

- Cast the characters to their scalar value: `'Z' as u32 - 'A' as u32`
- Use byte character literals: `b'Z' - b'A'`

Comment: There are several valid reasons to perform arithmetic on character code. One example is implement the ceaser cypher as: `char new = 'a' + (old - 'a' + 1) % 26`.

Comment: @KartikSoneji which is meaningless in a Unicode world and barely meaningful in an ASCII world. You'd do that on bytes after checking that they are indeed letters of the Latin alphabet.

Comment: Of course, but it saves a step, and feels more intuitive to me at least.
Another example is to check if a character is a valid character between a and m (for whatever reason): `if('a' <= ch && ch <= 'm')`. It eliminates magic numbers in the code and the meaning can be immediately grasped.

Comment: @KartikSoneji I'm not sure where you're going here. `char` does implement `PartialOrd`, this is completely orthogonal from `Sub`.

Comment: I come from languages like Java and C++, and am new to Rust. I assumed that if char did not implement `Sub` then it would not implement `PartialOrd` as well. Seems strange to me.

Comment: @KartikSoneji For example, in C++, Java and Rust, strings are comparable, but not subtractable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210548/discussion-between-kartik-soneji-and-mcarton).

Comment: RUST seems to have forgotten that the bottom 7 biuts of utf-8 are ascii

Comment: @teknopaul no it didn’t. But substracting ASCII characters only makes sense when the characters happen to be both lower case, both upper case or both digits. Rust tends to not make easy operations that only work for a very small subset of the values.

Comment: @mcarton there are applications beyond both lower case, both upper case or both digits. One would be in capitalizing or de-capitalizing texts. If there is an order, calculating distance between elements will frequently make sense in cases you cant foresee.

Comment: @maybesomename “capitalizing or de-capitalizing texts” does [not work with a simple offset](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/transforms/casemappings.html) in Unicode like it does with ASCII. “If there is an order, calculating distance between elements will frequently make sense” again, strings in most languages are orderable but you can't subtract them to get the distance between them. Why should Unicode scalar values (`char`) be any different?

Comment: @mcarto I was commenting only on " both lower case, both upper case or both digits" part.

Answer (score 2):

Math is not meaningless in unicode, that misses the most amazing feature of utf-8.

Any 7bit char with 0 high bit is valid us-ascii, a 7bit us-ascii doc is valid utf-8.  You can treat utf-8 as us-ascii bytes provided all comparisons and math deal with values lower than 127.
This is by design of utf-8, C code tends to just work, however rust makes this complicated.

Given a string  `value: &str`

Grab the bytes  `as_bytes()`

```
for byt in value.as_bytes() {
    let mut c = *byt; // c is u8 (unsigned byte)

    // if we are dealing with us-ascii chars...
    if c >= b'A' && c <= b'Z' {
        // math works, this converts to us-ascii lowercase
        c = c + 32;  
    }

    // to treat the u8 as a rust char cast it
    let ch = c as char;
    // now you can write sane code like  
    if ch == ':' || ch == ' ' || ch == '/' {
        ....
    // but you cant do math anymore
```

This math is not meaningless, `+32` is a handy lowercase function for A-Z             and this is valid treatment of utf-8 chars.

It is not by accident that `a + 1 = b` in utf-8.  Ascii-beticaly ordering may not be the same as real world alphabetical ordering, but it is still useful because it performs well over a common range of characters.

It is not meaningless that `'3' + 1 = '4'` in ascii.

You will not break strings utf-8 as bytes, simple code like `if (c == 'a')`  will work even if you have smiley poos in the string.

Doing math on Rust's char is impossible, which is a shame.

Doing math on one byte of a utf-8 string is as valid as its ever been.

Comment: You're completely missing the point of Unicode if you're doing this. If you only care about basic English strings, use ASCII and bytes. If you're using Unicode, use it correctly. This kind of math only works for simple strings, and is broken in general. If you don't care about proper Unicode handling, you can use `as_bytes`, and thanks to how Rust store strings, and how UTF-8 is defined, this is comes for free.

Comment: But don't pretend that your "math on UTF-8" method handles case correctly. It doesn't. It will ignore precomposed upper case letters and anything non-English. It doesn't handle `É`, it doesn't handle `Γ`. `c == 'a'` also won't work as expected for real-life strings, because of combining characters. Doing math on one byte of a UTF-8 string has never been correct.

Comment: As for ordering, this is completely orthogonal to addition. Strings are orderable, but no-one complains that they can't do `+ 1` on a string. And `'a' < 'b'` in Rust.

Comment: In general, if you use `char` or `str::chars` in your application, your application is probably broken on some valid strings.