# Is there a way to add an offset to a character in Rust?

Tags: string, rust, character, ascii

I come from a C/C++ background where ASCII bytes are easy to offset:

```c
char my_new_char = 'a' + some_offset;
```

It's my understanding that Rust uses UTF-8 for its `char`/`&str`/`String`, so the offset is not possible for all ranges.  However, offsetting in this way should still be feasible for characters in the ASCII range, correct?  UTF-8 mirrors ASCII for the overlapping range.

I was looking at the docs/searching around but I could not find a way to offset.  Is this possible in Rust?

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I subtract one character from another in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54583399/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: The duplicate applied to your case: `let my_new_char = ('a' as u8 + 1) as char;` or `let my_new_char = (b'a' + 1) as char;`

Comment: And the usual warning: you *really* should not be incrementing / decrementing text except in very small usecases. Many cases where it seems useful, you should just have bytes (`u8`) instead of characters (`char`) and slices / Vecs of bytes instead of strings.

Comment: Thank you for the help!  Apologies for the duplicate; I didn't run across that answer in my searches.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
fn f(c: char, n: i8) -> char {
    debug_assert!(c.is_ascii_alphanumeric());
    let ret = ((c as i8) + n) as u8 as char;
    debug_assert!(ret.is_ascii_alphanumeric());
    ret
}
```

This allows both positive and negative offsets, plus makes sure both the input and output are in the `[a-zA-Z0-9]` range (which is *usually* what you want in this context).

Comment: [`f('о', 10) = 'H'`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=888d40190a245d177ee88a115155f4fc)

Comment: Even better, `f('ŏ', 0) = 'O'`.

Comment: @trentcl Of course, we can also put a contract on the input. :)

Comment: May the downvoter please explain his/her reasoning? Thank you!